# Импорт PNG в программу

Tags: c++

Как импортировать картинку с форматом .png в программу (написанную на C++) и вывести её? Если можно, то предоставьте пример.

Answer (score 3):

*Один из возможных способов - прочитать эту самую картинку с помощью [**libpng.**](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html)*

- Вообще, вопрос очень сильно зависит от средств, используемых для рисования `Gui`. В случае `Qt`, `wxWidgets` и им же подобных, работа с `.png` и отрисовка проводится средствами самой библиотеки, однако, понятно, что способы сильно отличаются.
- В случае `WinAPI` имеет смысл прочитать эту картинку с помощью `libpng` в некоторый буфер и отрисовать ее из буфера в обработчике `WM_PAINT`.
- При использовании `C++ Builder`-подобной среды все выполняется с помощью класса `VCL` `TImage`.

Comment: Можете привести пример, как прочитать картинку с помощью `libpng`, а то при попытке скомпилировать пишет кучу ошибок.

Comment: Если используется WinAPI, то проще сразу использовать `Image::FromFile()` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535370(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: странно, подключил GDI+ использовал Image::FromFile(), при компиляции пишет кучу ошибок с winbase.h